# how to call server action in angular service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to call my server from index view and bring model from server to view

i have done but that is not working please tell how to do

here this is what i did

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
var CreateController = ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.mydata = 'ajs works';
    $http.get('/Testing/Index').success(function(data){
        $scope.model = data;

    })
    .error(function(data){
        console.log("error");
    });
}];
app.controller('CreateController', CreateController);
```

and here is the Index View

```
<div ng-controller="CreateController">
    <table class="ui-sortable-handle">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="{{model.Questions.AddQuestionID}}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="complevel" value="{{model.Questions.ComplexityLevel}}" />
                <input type="hidden" id="servcomplvl" value="{{model.servercomplevel}}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Question: {{model.Questions.Question}}</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in model.Options">
            <td class="switch radius">
                <input id="{{item.Options}}" type="radio" name="selectedvalue" value="{{item.Options}}">
                <label for="{{item.Options}}"></label>{{item.Options}}
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

what i return from view is

```
return View(vm);
```

Comment: Could you explain it litte more? what is the return View(vm)? And instead of using success in $http.get it is better to return a promise .then(function(response){})

Comment: vm is the object of viewmodel

Comment: i changed View(vm) with Json(vm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
now it returns json format but i dont need json

Comment: What is `return View(vm);`? Is this your server code? What do you mean by "I don't need json"? what do you want to return?

Comment: yeah it is server code and i want to return my server model to view and get there using angular

Comment: What is "server model"? Javascript works best with JSON - return JSON with the data and structure that you need and it should work fine.

Comment: i did this return Json(vm , JsonRequestbehavior.AllowGet); but still i am in trouble